# Error No such module 'GoogleSignIn' Xcode 10.2

Tags: swift

I updated cocoapods and reinstalled pods then a red and white target symbol appeared by frameworks in my targets
[My Targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjkPE.png)

I have previously installed 'GoogleSignIn' cocoapod and it works fine, but now when I try and build I get the error message **"No such module GoogleSignIn"**
I'm using cocoapods from other frameworks such as Firebase and it is working fine im using .xcworkspace, Xcode 10.2. 
I've tried:

1.Clean and rebuild.
2.Clean build folder.
3.Restart Xcode.
4.pod update/install.

My podfile looks like this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Dilblitz' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Dilblitz
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'ChameleonFramework'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'

end
```

Comment: Did you open the .xcworkspace after installing the pods?

Comment: Yes I'm using xcworkspace

Answer (score 0):

you are select Deployment Target 12.0 then build the code.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out for some reason when my podfile 'GoogleSignIn' was installing the framework file was not installing (In the left panel Pods-> GoogleSignIn) so I dragged it from another project I was working on, very odd

Comment: Can you elaborate on where you dragged it to and from